# how to save Properties.Settings.Default settings in our own file path instead of default configuration path?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, settings

I'm having some settings in `Properties.Settings.Default` in my dotnet application.
when i use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` it is getting saved in the exe configuration path or appdata path with respect to the application version.

I would like to save them in some specified path like `"C:\MyCustomConfigs\MyAppSettings.xml"`. I tried with the documentation and i couldn't  find any specific way to force the settings to be written in a specific path.

Is it possible to save the properties in the settings into some specific file path?

Comment: User settings are supposed to save in user home path.

Comment: You could implement a custom [SettingsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to save to a custom path.